# How to create a List using the paremetrized type of the generic class as the datype or Object?

Tags: java, generics

Is it anyway possible to create a list by using the parametrized TYPE
of the generic class? In the below code T is the parametrized type.
Any possible solutions?

```
package collectionsDemo;

import java.util.*;

public class ListDemo<T> {
    public void listCreator(){
        List<T> listDemo=new ArrayList<>();

       /*i intended to  add something like below Since
         T is type of Integer Object,which i can't perform right now.
         and below is the compile time error*/

          listDemo.add(34);
          listDemo.add(55);

       /*The method add(int, T) in the type List<T> is not 
          applicable for the  arguments (int)*/
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ListDemo<Integer> listdemo=new ListDemo<>();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want `listDemo` to store only Integers then why do you declare it as `List<T>` instead of `List<Integer>`? BTW don't name your different variables same, it is hard to explain things if we are using same name for different thing.

Comment: i want it to be generic,so code is flexible?am i wrong?

Comment: Based on your previous question I assume you also want to be able to store different type of objects beside there, which will depend on `ListDemo<UsedType>`. In that case `List<T>` is correct choice, but since it will be able to represent list of many kind of objects like `List<Cat>`, `List<Dog>` you shouldn't be able to add `Cat` to `List<T>` because it can happen that it will be reference to `List<Dog>`.

Comment: @Pshemo thank you!a clarification,how do i solve this kind of problems and what is the simplest approach for the above problem.

Comment: Are you sure that `List<T> listDemo=new ArrayList<>();` must be local variable of `listCreator` method? Wouldn't it be better to make it field of your class? This way you could create some method like `addToMyList(T element)` and use it like `ListDemo<Integer> demo = new ListDemo<>(); demo.addToList(1);`

Comment: But in that case I am not sure why you even need `ListDemo<T>` class. You could simply use `List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(); list.add(1)` or `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(); list.add("foo");`

Comment: Well,it might sounds wired,had an assignment to reduce the length of code by 50% which i am trying to do and i thought it might be a good practice to make it generic and hence i less code and more performance.

Comment: what are you going to do post list is created? Are you intending to reuse the list somehow?

Comment: @Terminator If your problem is solved, you should either indicate who solved the problem by accepting/voting on the answer, or if you solved it yourself, post the answer yourself. This helps future users who may have a similar issue solve their problem.

Comment: @Pshemo please take a look at the code i have posted!!

Comment: @JGrice please take a look at the code i have posted!!

Answer (score 0):

No. This is not the way you can do it.

You can not store an `int` in a list that wants a element of type `T`.

`ListDemo<T>` and `List<T>`, in both these cases, the type parameter `T` is different.

You need to do this:

```
List<Integer> listDemo = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then, and only Then, you cad `add` integers in your list.

Comment: What do you want to achieve basically? Actually it all depends upon your target. Only then I will be able to tell you whats the best practice for that.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to answer my own question and i am not sure whether it is best practice or not?Correct me if i am wrong!

```
*package collectionsDemo;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class GenericListCreator<T> {
        public void listCreator( T[] e){
            List<T> listDemo=new ArrayList<>();
            for(T t:e){
                listDemo.add(t);
            }
            for(T t:e){
                System.out.println(t);
            }
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            GenericListCreator<Integer> age=new GenericListCreator<>();
            age.listCreator(new Integer[]{21,22,24});
            GenericListCreator<String> name=new GenericListCreator<>();
            name.listCreator(new String[]{"John","michell","bing"});
            GenericListCreator<Double> price=new GenericListCreator<>();
            price.listCreator(new Double[]{23.5,556.5,55.6});
        }
    }*
```

Comment: It is acceptable, but you may find some problems with `T[]` if instead of `new Integer[]` you will try `new int[]`. Also I still don't see any reason to create separate class. You can achieve similar results with `List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(); list.addAll(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));`

Comment: @Pshemo thanks,will keep that in mind not to repeat common mistakes.